# Chrome: Serviceworker Won't Transition To Running State When Receiving Push Message

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, notifications, service-worker, push-api

We have implemented an SDK to ease the process of sending and receiving Push Notification. However, recently we are facing an issue that results in receiving `Generic Notification`(i.e., This site has been updated in the background) message whenever we send a push message.

After a period of inspection and trial-and-error, we came to the rough conclusion that:

- Whenever we send a Push Notification, **the first time around**, service worker won't wake up and hang in the `Stopped` state. As a result,`Generic Notification` is shown. In immediate subsequent Push Messages, service worker transitions to `Running` state and receives Push Messages.
- The following code responsible for handling `push` event is not invoked **the first time** sending Push Message.

```
@serviceWorkerEvent('push')
    public static async onPushEvent(context: Context, event: PushEvent) {
        context.api.pushDelivered({
            // Sending Analytics
        }).catch(e => log.error('e'));

        const notificationOptions: NotificationOptions = {
            // Notification Options
        };

        const notifTitle = notificationData.title || '';
        await (await context.serviceWorker.registration).showNotification(notifTitle, notificationOptions);

        await context.workerMessenger.broadcast(WORKER_MESSAGE_TYPES.PUSH_RECEIVED, notificationData);
    }
```

P.S. Using a wrapper function containing `event.waitUntil()`, we are awaiting for the promises  inside to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior. Your service worker is not handling the first `push` event because your page is still an **uncontrolled client** for it. Your service worker is not yet in the `active` state.

From [The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle) (a highly recommended read):

> A service worker won't receive events like fetch and push until it successfully finishes installing and becomes "active".

To handle the first `push` event you can either:

1. call `location.reload()` in your service worker registration script
2. call `clients.claim()` in your service worker

Option 2 overrides the default behavior of the service worker and let it take control of uncontrolled clients (your sw immediately *claims* the clients).

See also:

- [Refresh page on controllerchange in service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891031/refresh-page-on-controllerchange-in-service-worker)
- [Recommended Approach for Refreshing Page on new SW](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1120)

Comment: I actually managed to solve the issue. We have been neglectful of a warning stating that "Your serviceworker events have to be registered eariler". Its helpful to note that the serviceworker was already activated and in control of different events.